# Rtsp h264 video stream stuttering using QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, h.264, rtsp

I am trying to visualize a h264 rtsp video stream from an IP Camera with pyqt5, the video keeps stuttering. I have tried to use a local video, it played smootly. I also used python vlc api to stream, but then I couldn't implement some other stuff I wanted to do. Is there a way to fix the stuttering (like vlc network chatching)?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget


class Player(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handle_error)

        self.videowidget = QVideoWidget()

        # video stutters
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl("rtsp://<address>:<port>")))

        # video plays smoothly
        # fileName = "C:\\Users\\...\\test.mp4"
        # self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videowidget.videoSurface())
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

        main_lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        main_lay.addWidget(self.videowidget)
        self.setLayout(main_lay)

    def handle_error(self):
        print("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    player = Player()
    player.show()
    player.resize(640, 480)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```